# Python Imaging Library vs layered windows

Tags: python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I'm using Python Imaging Library to take a screenshot and save it. I'm trying to take a screenshot of a program that uses layered windows, but it doesn't show up on the image. Does anyone know a way around this or maybe some other way to get the image into memory? Thanks

```
import ImageGrab
import os
import time

im = ImageGrab.grab()
im.save(os.getcwd() + "\\snap_" + str(time.strftime("%H-%M-%S")) + ".jpg","JPEG")
```

Comment: Please state your operating system (and window manager) if applicable. "Layered windows" is a  generic expression (unless it is not in some specific environment)

Comment: Does your deseired content show up when you take an interacttive screenshot with the "print screen"  key?

Comment: Sorry, it's Windows 7. Yes, the program I want a picture up shows up when I use the PrtScrn button, but when I use PIL the program is invisible. I assume it's because it uses layered windows